# Same height at 2 elements

Tags: html, css, height

I have this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="leftmenu">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        dada
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0r9ptmsr/

I want to make content element at same height with leftmenu only with CSS, without JS.

Comment: give equal height for both classes

Comment: `Did you try to add html, body {height: 100%;}` to your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is give `position: relative;` to parent container i.e. `.page-container` and `position: absolute;` to child.

And give height and width 100% to child div.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0r9ptmsr/3/)**

```
.page-container { 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.content{
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
 position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ".content" class, write "height : 1000px;"

Comment: oh you are a genous, i'm ironic u know

Answer (score 0):

give both of them same height for example `1000px;`

```
.content, .leftmenu{
    height: 1000px;
}
```

like this :

```css
.container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.page-container { overflow: hidden; }

.leftmenu {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);   
    background-color: black;
}

.content {
     margin-left: 230px;
    background: #f3f4f6;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);   
    background-color: yellow;
}
.content, .leftmenu{
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="leftmenu">
      
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            dada
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.page-container { overflow: hidden; height:1000px; }

.leftmenu {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);   
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
     margin-left: 230px;
    background: #f3f4f6;
    height: 100%;
    
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);   
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="leftmenu">
      
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            dada
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the content height and box-sizing as

```
.content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 1000px;
}
```